# Mule ESB - How to evaluate expression in custom java transformer

Tags: mule

In a Mule ESB custom java transformer, how can expressions be evaluated from java code?

The MuleContext has an expression manager with an evaluate method that works great. However, the signature accepting a MuleMessage is deprecated and the non-deprecated version requires a MuleEvent. A MuleEvent is not available from a transformer, just a MuleMessage.

Basically what I want to use is this:

```
muleContext.getExpressionManager().evaluate(someValue, message);
```

Another way to access the MuleEvent is/was to use the static `RequestContext.getEvent()`. That is, however, also deprecated. I have been successful in creating a static variable with a `ThreadLocal<MuleEvent>`, injecting the MuleEvent early in the flow via a MessageProcessor, but it feels totally wrong and possible not really the safest approach.

Am I missing something? Is there another way? There is not much guidance in the deprecated notes in java docs about migration paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid the deprecated method, you can use

```
evaluate(String expression, String evaluator, MuleMessage message, boolean failIfNull)
```

If your expression is just MEL, use `null` as `evaluator`, otherwise it is the prefix of your expression (json etc).

Comment: Thanks. That might do the trick.
The deprecated methods using MuleMessage seems to invoke this particular method after splitting the expression language from the expression. 

The MuleEvent based methods seems to just extract the message from the event and reuse the deprecated MuleMessage based methods under the hood. I am still confused about the sense in this api, but case closed..